# Converting to GetX raises issues

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety, flutter-getx

I am converting my flutter app to use GetX rather than provider and during the conversion I am getting some errors that I don't know how to correct.

**First error:**

In my data model, AgentsModel, I am getting an error in the method AgentsModel.fromSnapshot(). The error is a null safety error. I have tried putting a "?" in the declaration of the parameter being passed in but it does not help.

**Error message:**

The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

**Agents.dart** data model file

```
class AgentsModel {
  final String? agentId;
  final String? fName;
  final String? lName;
  final String? agency;
  final String? agencyId;
  final String? address1;
  final String? address2;
  final String? city;
  final String? state;
  final int? zipcode;
  final String? cellPhone;
  final String? officePhone;
  final String? email;
  final String? mls;
  final String? mlsId;

  AgentsModel(
      {this.cellPhone,
      this.address1,
      this.address2,
      this.fName,
      this.lName,
      this.email});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'cellPhone': cellPhone,
      'address1': address1,
      'address2': address2,
      'fName': fName,
      'lName': lName,
      'email': email
    };
  }

  AgentsModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : cellPhone = snapshot.data()['cellPhone'] ?? null,
        address1 = snapshot.data()['address1'] ?? null,
        address2 = snapshot.data()['address2'] ?? null,
        fName = snapshot.data()['fName'] ?? null,
        lName = snapshot.data()['lName'] ?? null,
        email = snapshot.data()['email'] ?? null;
}
```

**Error 2 (related to error 1):**

In my auth_controller.dart file I am getting an error where I am declaring my agentsModel variable. Here is the error:

```
A value of type 'Rx<AgentsModel>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Rxn<AgentsModel>'
```

Here is the line of code throwing the error:

```
  Rxn<AgentsModel> agentsModel = AgentsModel().obs;
```

**Error 3 (related to the first 2 errors)**

When I try to call fromSnapshot() from the auth_controller.dart file I am getting and error on the call, agentsModel.fromSnapshot(doc));, stating

The method 'fromSnapshot' isn't defined for the type 'Rxn'.

```
_initializeUserModel(String userId) async {
    agentsModel.value =
      await _db.collection(agentsCollection)
        .doc(userId)
        .get()
        .then((doc) => agentsModel.fromSnapshot(doc));
  }
```

Here is the definition again from above:

```
  AgentsModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : cellPhone = snapshot.data()['cellPhone'] ?? null,
        address1 = snapshot.data()['address1'] ?? null,
        address2 = snapshot.data()['address2'] ?? null,
        fName = snapshot.data()['fName'] ?? null,
        lName = snapshot.data()['lName'] ?? null,
        email = snapshot.data()['email'] ?? null;
}
```

**Bonus error (not related to the above errors)**
I am getting an error on declaring a firebaseUser variable.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
```

Error on the below line is The class 'User' doesn't have a default constructor.

```
  User firebaseUser = User().obs;
```

Error for below line is A value of type 'Rx' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'User'.

```
  firebaseUser = Rx<User>(auth.currentUser);
```

Error for below line is he method 'bindStream' isn't defined for the type 'User'.

```
  firebaseUser.bindStream(auth.userChanges());
```

Since some of these errors are related to null safety I have added "?" and "!" but with no change. I'm new and learning so any help I can get will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- For example you declare `var x = bool.obs`. To access value of x you need `x.value` not `x`.
- `obs` is not decoration. It is a shortcut for instantiating an `Rx` object. That means `bool.obs != bool`
- Use `!` operator, to force null when you are sure it isn't. *(Error 1)*

##### Error 2 - type mismatch, use var in such cases.

```dart
var agentsModel = AgentsModel().obs;
```

##### Error 3 - you need to call `value` property.

```dart
agentsModel.value.fromSnapshot(doc))
```

##### Bonus errors

Same as error 2 and 3

Comment: thanks for your response. For error 1, I have tried cellPhone = snapshot.data()!['cellPhone'] ?? null adding the "!" but it then says that cellPhone is not defined. Where would I add the "!" at?  Error 2 is fixed now. For the bonus error, I change to declaring as a var (var firebaseUser = User().obs;) but now I get The class 'User' doesn't have a default constructor. I have tried User.instance.obs but it does not work.

Comment: I changed final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance  to    var auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;  This now gives me an error on the line     firebaseUser = Rxn<User>auth.currentUser; saying "The operator '<' isn't defined for the type 'Type'."

Comment: In most case IDE will help you to put proper `!` operator.